# Making game gravity, everything goes way too quickly

Tags: java, awt, gravity

So basically i'm currently working on a small project where the player will be able to fight stuff through move but the gravity is giving me kind of a problem. So basically, i got this method, checkGravity() which will check if isGravityApplicable() return true (does the entity's bottom collider(a Line2D) collide with one of the foothold?(another line2D))

If isGravityApplicable() returns true, then the gravity should be applied but the problem that i have is that anything above 1 pixel Y is way too quickly and even, moving the character by one pixel is extremely fast. I'm not sure whether i should fix my game loop or what?

```
public boolean isGravityApplicable() {
    for (Line2D line : frame.getMap().getFootholds()) {
        /*Does the bottom collider intersect the foothold?*/
        /*v THIS CHECK DOESN'T WORK CORRECTLY FOR SOME REASONS v*/
        if (!GraphicHelper.getLineCameraRelative(getBottomCollider(), frame.getCam()).intersectsLine(line)) {
            return true;
        }
        /*Above check returned false, if the velocity.y is above 1, then it might
         skip the line since it would be skipping 5 pixels for example at once.
         this check should resolve that.*/
        if (velocity.y > 0) {
            Line2D collider = getPositionToVelocityCollider();
            if (!collider.intersectsLine(line)) {
                position.y = (int) line.getY1(); //Y1 or Y2, same sh*t.
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void checkGravity() {
    if (isGravityApplicable()) {
        if (isJumping) { //Player has jumped
            velocity.y += 1;
            velocity.y = velocity.y > TERMINAL_ACCELERATION ? (int) TERMINAL_ACCELERATION : velocity.y;
            if (velocity.y < 0) {
                isFalling = true;
            }
        } else if (isFalling) { //Player is currently falling but not from jumping. Most likely just spawned
            velocity.y = 1;
            /*Anything higher than 1 is WAY too quickly...*/
            //velocity.y += 1;
            //velocity.y = velocity.y > TERMINAL_VELOCITY ? (int) TERMINAL_VELOCITY : velocity.y;
        } else if (isJumping && isFalling) { //Player has jumped and has reached its highest point, falling back down
            velocity.y = 1;
            /*Anything higher than 1 is WAY too quickly...*/
            //velocity.y += 1;
            //velocity.y = velocity.y > TERMINAL_VELOCITY ? (int) TERMINAL_VELOCITY : velocity.y;
        } else { //Player hasn't jumped and has not started falling, he most likely just spawned
            isFalling = true;
            velocity.y = 1;
        }
    } else {
        isFalling = false;
        isJumping = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance. Oh and if there is anything i could of done better like the collisions which consist of simple lines all around the entities, please tell me. :) Thanks.

Comment: Your gameloop speed needs to be controlled http://obviam.net/index.php/the-android-game-loop/

Comment: @NicolasMartel you need to integrate each update accordingly i.e using the time step.

Comment: @NicolasMartel by the way your code currently won't ever reach the `else if (isJumping && isFalling)` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys, for some reason the update/tick method was called twice in the loop for some reasons. I guess i had a brain fart or something.